# Publicar sitio en IIS conectado con SAP BO , Error: "ExceptionMessage": "You are not connected to a company"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sap, windows-server-2016

recientemente estoy integrando SAP BO, pero esta vez he creado un API en .net con C# desde Visual Studio, cuando consumo mi API desde Postman teniendola en mi local, todo funciona bastante bien y la conexión, registro y visualización en SAP es exitosa, pero cuando publico mi API en IIS me da un error que es el siguiente:

"ExceptionMessage": "You are not connected to a company",
"ExceptionType": "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException"

Estoy utilizando DI API 9.0, Windows Server 2016, ya he buscado la forma de resolver este problema y aún no lo consigo:

Esta imagen es del API ya publicad en IIS donde solo me deja ver los registros, pero no me deja ingresar nuevos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta es de mi local, donde me deja visualizar, registrar y modificar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco su ayuda, de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día a todos, espero poder ayudar a alguien con esto.
Después de varios días intentando solucionar el problema, lo logré.

Hice algunas configuraciones del lado de IIS y Windows:

1. Dar permisos a todos los usuarios de IIS (Full control)
2. Bajar el firewall de windows, esto lo he hecho en windows server 2016.
3. Eliminar DI API desde el panel de control.
4. Borrar carpeta temporal con Win + R = %temp%.
5. Volver a instalar el DI API.
6. Fijarse bien en el puerto que utiliza el SLD de Sap, para no poner uno incorrecto en tu conexión, eso lo puedes consultar en:
   Program Files (x86) -> SAP -> SAP Business One Server Tools -> Conf -> b1-local-machine.
7. En la conexión puse la IP de mi servidor o bien el nombre del servidor, por ejemplo:

   Con el nombre del servidor:
   oCompany.SLDServer = "PRUEBASAP:30010";
   oCompany.LicenseServer = "PRUEBASAP:30000";

   Con la IP del servidor:
   oCompany.SLDServer = "52.167.130.01:30010";
   oCompany.LicenseServer = "52.167.130.01:30000";
8. Por último el UseTrusted lo coloqué de "true" a false.

Espero les sirva de ayuda. :)